# Why does this function not output decimals

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
void LocalMax(vector<Station> Entry , int Size)
{
    int Highest1 = 0, Highest2 = 0, Highest3 = 0, Temp = 0, Highest = 0;
    double TempDouble;
    for (int i = 0; i < Size - 1; i++)
    {
        Temp = Entry[i].MaxTemp;
        if (Temp > Highest) {Highest = 0; Highest = Temp;}
        if (Entry[i].StationID != Entry[(i + 1)].StationID)
            {
                if (Entry[i].StationID == "GHCND:USC00083909") {Highest1 = Highest; Highest = 0;}
                if (Entry[i].StationID == "GHCND:USW00012888") {Highest2 = Highest; Highest = 0;}
                if (Entry[i].StationID == "GHCND:USR0000FCHE") {Highest3 = Highest;}
            } else if (Temp > Highest) {Highest = Temp; Temp = 0;}
        if (i == Size - 2) {Highest3 = Highest;}
    }
    TempDouble = Highest1 / 10;
    cout << "The highest temp recorded for Station1 was: " << Highest1 << " tenths of a degree Celsius \nor: " << TempDouble << " degrees Celsius." << endl;
    TempDouble = Highest2 / 10;
    cout << "The highest temp recorded for Station2 was: " << Highest2 << " tenths of a degree Celsius \nor: " << TempDouble << " degrees Celsius." << endl;
    TempDouble = Highest3 / 10;
    cout << "The highest temp recorded for Station3 was: " << Highest3 << " tenths of a degree Celsius \nor: " << TempDouble << " degrees Celsius." << endl;
}
```

that gives me:

```
The highest temp recorded for Station1 was: 339 tenths of a degree Celsius
or: 33 degrees Celsius.
The highest temp recorded for Station2 was: 350 tenths of a degree Celsius
or: 35 degrees Celsius.
The highest temp recorded for Station3 was: 344 tenths of a degree Celsius
or: 34 degrees Celsius.
```

Why does it not show any decimals for TempDouble?  Any clarification would be great!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code performs integer division. That's because both operands are integers.

```
TempDouble = Highest1 / 10;
```

Integer division yields an integer result. Yes, it is true that you then assign that integer to a floating point value, but it is too late. You have already lost the fractional part of the division.

You need to make at least one of your operands be a real value to get real division.

For instance:

```
TempDouble = Highest1 / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This line performs *integer* division because the left and right operands of `/` are `int`s:

```
TempDouble = Highest1 / 10;
```

To get a `double`, ensure one of the the operands is a `double`. The easiest way is this:

```
TempDouble = Highest1 / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of integer arithmetic is an integer. If you want a floating point result you need to involve a floating point number in the expression, e.g.:

```
 TempDouble = Highest1 / 10.0;
```